DockerDesktop "starting Kubernetes" for ever
I tried to enable Kubernetes in my DockerDesktop but it showed  "starting Kubernetes" for ever.
Following is the output when I run kubectl get commands:
C:\Users\al>kubectl get all -n kube-system
E1103 22:34:05.904780   23432 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api?timeout=32s": EOF
...

C:\Users\al>kubectl get nodes -v=10
I1103 22:28:50.038997   39088 loader.go:395] Config loaded from file:  C:\Users\al\.kube\config
I1103 22:28:50.042998   39088 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json;g=apidiscovery.k8s.io;v=v2;as=APIGroupDiscoveryList,application/json;g=apidiscovery.k8s.io;v=v2beta1;as=APIGroupDiscoveryList,application/json" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.30.2 (windows/amd64) kubernetes/3968350" 'https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api?timeout=32s'
I1103 22:28:50.058327   39088 round_trippers.go:495] HTTP Trace: DNS Lookup for kubernetes.docker.internal resolved to [{127.0.0.1 }]
I1103 22:28:50.059337   39088 round_trippers.go:510] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:127.0.0.1:6443 succeed
I1103 22:28:50.059849   39088 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api?timeout=32s  in 16 milliseconds
I1103 22:28:50.059849   39088 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 14 ms Dial 0 ms TLSHandshake 0 ms Duration 16 ms
I1103 22:28:50.059849   39088 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
I1103 22:28:51.069512   39088 with_retry.go:234] Got a Retry-After 1s response for attempt 1 to https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api?timeout=32s
...

In hosts file, I can see:
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.2.12 host.docker.internal
192.168.2.12 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal

how do I deal with this situation?
